# How to create a new SHA 1 key for new project ?I have created that one by using cd android./gradlew signingReport

Tags: firebase, react-native, sha

i am creating a project but when i use my sha-1 key in fire base it give error of update that this sha-1 key and package name is already in use. The question is that how to create a unique sha 1 key for every project because it is same when i use the command in my pc

Comment: you need to change your package name because you can not make two applications with the same package name.

Comment: @AnkitVora I createad a new project in react native having different package name.

Comment: also, you have created a different project for firebase..?

Comment: yes absolutly i have created different project on firebase even i used firebase from another gmail account

Comment: I have to known that SHA-1 key of a system is always remain same?

Comment: Yes SHA1 and SHA256 both are same in your any project.

Comment: keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

>>>>> Fire this command in android project, if you have Mac .

Comment: It means i should have different project package name only while connecting to firebase fore google signin

Comment: Yes it should be Different.

Comment: @AnkitVora i have windows pc and and i get SHA-1 by using cd android ./gredlew signingReport ........ I also get it from android studio signing reports

Comment: I will  vote for your answer